# How to extract data from live log and pipe it to postgres

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, awk, sed

I need help with awk/grep/sed or whatever you think can do the job.
I have a log file and need to continuously monitor it and get some data out of the new lines as they are written to it.

The new lines are very long and not structured but they will contain the following pattern `UserName=SOMEUSRNAME, NetworkDevice=SOMENETWORKDEVICE, Calling-Station-ID=SOMEMACADDRESS`.

Exmaple:
`May 15 03:59:16 MTN-LAB-ISE-B1 CISE_Passed_Authentications 0000043297 1 0 2017-05-15 03:59:16.979 +00:00 0013123384 5200 NOTICE Passed-Authentication: Authentication succeeded, ConfigVersionId=170, Device IP Address=10.97.31.130, DestinationIPAddress=10.62.56.152, DestinationPort=1812, UserName=abcd\testuser, Protocol=Radius, RequestLatency=313, NetworkDeviceName=SHROCLUSW-WLAN-LAB, User-Name=d4d748fefe96, NAS-IP-Address=10.97.31.130, NAS-Port=50005, Service-Type=Call Check, Framed-IP-Address=10.97.109.64, Framed-MTU=1500, Called-Station-ID=64-E9-50-B6-DE-05, Calling-Station-ID=D4-D7-48-FE-FE-96, NAS-Port-Type=Ethernet, NAS-Port-Id=GigabitEthernet0/5, EAP-Key-Name=,`

I was thinking using tail -f to monitor the log file and pipe it to grep/sed/awk to extract the needed data.
I only need the SOMEUSERNAME, SOMENETWORKDEVICE, SOMEMACADDRESS and not the pattern also.

And of course to make this even more complicated after the extraction is done I need to pipe it to postgres.

Can someone give me a hint on how to do matching/extraction part and maybe the pipe to postgres?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
Please show what you have tried, including the part with tail.

Answer (score 0):

This might be done with grep/sed as well but I personally prefer awk.

I did this short script `filter.awk`:

```
{
  # find info in line
  userName = gensub(/^.*UserName=([^,\r\n]+).*$/, "\\1", 1, $0)
  networkDevice = gensub(/^.*NetworkDeviceName=([^,\r\n]+).*$/, "\\1", 1, $0)
  callingStationId = gensub(/^.*Calling-Station-ID=([^,\r\n]+).*$/, "\\1", 1, $0)
  # print filtered info (if any of patterns matched)
  if (userName != "" || networkDevice != "" || callingStationId != "") {
    print "INSERT INTO logs (username, networkdevice, calling_station_id) VALUES ('"userName"', '"networkDevice"', '"callingStationId"');"
  }
  # If "all patterns" is required instead of "any pattern"
  # the "||" operators have to be replaced with "&&".
}
```

I tested it with GNU awk on bash in cygwin (Window 10):

```
$ cat >filter.txt <<EOF
> May 15 03:59:16 MTN-LAB-ISE-B1 CISE_Passed_Authentications 0000043297 1 0 2017-05-15 03:59:16.979 +00:00 0013123384 5200 NOTICE Passed-Authentication: Authentication succeeded, ConfigVersionId=170, Device IP Address=10.97.31.130, DestinationIPAddress=10.62.56.152, DestinationPort=1812, UserName=abcd\testuser, Protocol=Radius, RequestLatency=313, NetworkDeviceName=SHROCLUSW-WLAN-LAB, User-Name=d4d748fefe96, NAS-IP-Address=10.97.31.130, NAS-Port=50005, Service-Type=Call Check, Framed-IP-Address=10.97.109.64, Framed-MTU=1500, Called-Station-ID=64-E9-50-B6-DE-05, Calling-Station-ID=D4-D7-48-FE-FE-96, NAS-Port-Type=Ethernet, NAS-Port-Id=GigabitEthernet0/5, EAP-Key-Name=,
> EOF

$ awk -f filter.awk filter.txt
INSERT INTO logs (username, networkdevice, calling_station_id) VALUES ('abcd\testuser', 'SHROCLUSW-WLAN-LAB', 'D4-D7-48-FE-FE-96');

$
```

Notes:

1. The `NetworkDevice=` pattern doesn't seem to be sufficient for me. I replaced it with `NetworkDeviceName=`. (It should be easy to replace this if I'm wrong.)
2. I do not know how to format output correctly for `postgres` nor do I know the database structure of the questioner. Thus, the `print` statement probably has to be adjusted. (There is only one `print` statement in script.) However, the `print` statement outputs to standard output channel (what you already might have expected). Thus, it can be piped into any other input consuming process easily.
3. It is unclear whether it is required that all patterns must match or (instead) at least one.
   I implemented "at least one".
   To implement "all", the `||` operators in the `if` statement had to be replaced by `&&` operators. (There is only one `if` statement in script.)
4. Unfortunately, the `gensub()` function is available in GNU awk only. For non-GNU awk, another solution could be done using `gsub()` instead. However, the `gensub()` function is much more convenient to use. Thus, I prefer it as long as a non-GNU awk solution is not explicitly required.